# How to convert the RGB color model to the HSV color model in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, python-parser

How to convert the RGB color model to the HSV color model in ArcGIS Pro with Python parser?

I'm trying Calculate Field Tool, everything seems correct but it doesn't work!

Method (1)

Code Block:

```py
import colorsys

def RGBtoHSV(r, g, b):
    r /= 255.0
    g /= 255.0
    b /= 255.0
    hsv = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b)
    h = hsv[0] * 360
    s = hsv[1] * 100
    v = hsv[2] * 100
    return round(h, 2), round(s, 2), round(v, 2)
```

Expression:

```py
RGBtoHSV(!Red!, !Green!, !Blue!)
```

Method (2):

Code Block:

```py
def RGBtoHSV(r, g, b):
    r /= 255.0
    g /= 255.0
    b /= 255.0
    cmax = max(r, g, b)
    cmin = min(r, g, b)
    delta = cmax - cmin
    if delta == 0:
        h = 0
    elif cmax == r:
        h = 60 * (((g - b) / delta) % 6)
    elif cmax == g:
        h = 60 * (((b - r) / delta) + 2)
    else:
        h = 60 * (((r - g) / delta) + 4)
    if cmax == 0:
        s = 0
    else:
        s = (delta / cmax) * 100
    v = cmax * 100
    return round(h, 2), round(s, 2), round(v, 2)
```

Expression:

```py
RGBtoHSV(!Red!, !Green!, !Blue!)
```

Comment: You can easily use the Color Model Conversion function from Analysis>Raster Functions> Color Model Conversion. Here is an example of Color Space conversion using arcpy: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/image-analyst/colorspaceconversion.htm.

Comment: What do you mean by doesnt work? Do you get error messages?

Comment: I'm encountering a perplexing situation where I find myself devoid of any errors or results. Despite utilizing ArcGIS 3.01 and working with a locally stored shapefile layer, I seem to be facing a roadblock in obtaining the desired outcome.